# How do I iterate through each TD and TR in a table using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanna provide a Table including a Filter input, the User should input any digits and underneath in the table it should display the row with closest finding.

Lets say I wanna search by 11847, it doesn't show anything, but it should show the row.

Below is a working snippet and my Html and JS which i have so far. But it will loop only through the first column. I know this is according to this piece of code:

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```

But haven't figured it out how to get this done.

```js
function reservationListFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("reservationListInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("reservationTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#reservationListInput {
  background-image: url('./assets/bootstrap/fonts/searchicon.png');
  /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
}

#reservationTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase font-size */
}

#reservationTable th,
#reservationTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Add padding */
}

#reservationTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#reservationTable tr.header,
#reservationTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="reservationListInput" onkeyup="reservationListFunction()" placeholder="Search for reservation..">

<table id="reservationTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:40%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Cabin</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Table</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>49222</td>
    <td>201</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>12846</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>Inhouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>11847</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>Cancelled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>9876</td>
    <td>253</td>
    <td>Partial</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the problem is you are checking in only first td.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` will return the first `td` within the `tr` you're looping through. That's what the `[0]` part is - it's referencing the `0` index of the array that `getElementsByTagName()` returns.

To access all of the `td`'s in the row you're looping through, you need to remove the `[0]` index, and loop through the `td`'s returned with `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")` instead.

Also excluded the `.header` row from being tested, and am breaking the loop of your `td`'s if the filter returns a match.

```js
function reservationListFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("reservationListInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("reservationTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    if (!tr[i].classList.contains('header')) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"),
      match = false;
      for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
        if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          match = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!match) {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#reservationListInput {
  background-image: url('./assets/bootstrap/fonts/searchicon.png');
  /* Add a search icon to input */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  /* Position the search icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Do not repeat the icon image */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  /* Add some space below the input */
}

#reservationTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Collapse borders */
  width: 100%;
  /* Full-width */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  /* Add a grey border */
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Increase font-size */
}

#reservationTable th,
#reservationTable td {
  text-align: left;
  /* Left-align text */
  padding: 12px;
  /* Add padding */
}

#reservationTable tr {
  /* Add a bottom border to all table rows */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#reservationTable tr.header,
#reservationTable tr:hover {
  /* Add a grey background color to the table header and on hover */
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="reservationListInput" onkeyup="reservationListFunction()" placeholder="Search for reservation..">

<table id="reservationTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:40%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Cabin</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Table</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>49222</td>
    <td>201</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>12846</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>Inhouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>11847</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>Cancelled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>9876</td>
    <td>253</td>
    <td>Partial</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This fixes my Problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Chris sweet, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code:

```
<table id="reservationTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:40%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Cabin</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Table</th>
    <th style="width:20%;">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>49222</td>
    <td>201</td>
    <td>Expected</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>12846</td>
    <td>300</td>
    <td>Inhouse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>11847</td>
    <td>234</td>
    <td>Cancelled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>9876</td>
    <td>253</td>
    <td>Partial</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="reservationListInput" placeholder="Search Reservation"></input>
```

Below is search code, it iterates through each row to find the second column. Let me know if you are not able to get the desired result.

```
 $("#reservationListInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        $("table tr").each(function(index) {
            if (index !== 0) {

                $row = $(this);

                var id = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)").text();

                if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                    $row.hide();
                }
                else {
                    $row.show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Basically I need to iterate through each row and check each cell if the content from the search input is present.

Comment: So, you want any input to search either cabin or name..right..let me try